# c# IndexOf method

Tags: c#, list

I need to return the specific index of Node type List. In java, it can be done with `array1.get(index)` method but in c# it throws `error cannot convert int from Node`

I know this isn't optimal solution but is there a way to do with this method?
Below is my code.

```
List<DNode> array1 = new List<DNode>();

DNode temp = doubleLinkedList.head;
while(temp.next != null)
{
    array1.Add(temp);
    temp = temp.next;
}
return array1.IndexOf(1);
```

Comment: Did you mean `return array1[1];`? `IndexOf` searches for an element that matches the argument you pass in and returns its index

Comment: `IndexOf` returns the index of the argument.  Since your `List` is of type `DNode`, you would need to provide it with a `DNode`.

You can just use array accessors for this.  `return array1[1];`

Comment: What made you think that `.get(index)` is the same as `.IndexOf(index)`? You're probably looking for `.ElementAt(index)` if you want a direct comparison.

Comment: Direct accessor has solved the problem. I thought I needed .IndexOf method to access it.

Comment: In .NET Arrays there is a method `array.GetValue(index)` which is an equivalent to the indexer access `array[index]`, but actually I've never seen someone using it, more over you are actually working on a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I suggest you do. Iterating the linked list outside of the linked list means you need to repeatedly write that code. You're better off implementing an `IEnumerator<DNode>` inside `DNode` to make this work easily for you.

Here's how:

```
public class DNode : IEnumerable<DNode>
{
    public DNode Head;
    public DNode Next;

    public IEnumerator<DNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        DNode current = this.Head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

NB: I changed the property/field naming convention to C# standards, rather than Java. Sorry about that.

Now you can write your list building code like this:

```
List<DNode> array1 = doubleLinkedList.Head.ToList();
```